# What is NoSQL? How it works?

Tags: sql, nosql, distributed

Does NoSQL mean non-relational database?
How do you query such database?

Please can somebody put some insight into this field and help me to decide when it is good to use **NoSQL rather then SQL**. Are there any specific advantages in distributed environments?

**Edit**
Removing question *How it works internally?* because of so many different NoSQL databases existing out there.